# Question about fetch_openml in scikit-Learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dataset

I am using sklearn 0.24.0 and Python 3.8.

When I run,

```
mice = fetch_openml(name='miceprotein', version=4)
```

I get this error message:

```
RuntimeWarning: Invalid cache, redownloading file
  warn("Invalid cache, redownloading file", RuntimeWarning)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SSLCertVerificationError                  Traceback (most recent call last)
```

This is the last line of the error:

```
URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1125)>
```

I get this error with other datasets too. For e.g.,

```
mnist = fetch_openml('mnist_784', version=1, cache=True)
```

Any ideas, what's happening?

Answer (score 3):

I was also facing the same issue. Used following workaround. Worked!

```python
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

X, y = datasets.fetch_openml('mnist_784', version=1, return_X_y=True)
```

[image: ssl error openml]